# C# project referencing C++ DLL, getting System.AccessViolationException (Attempted to read or write protected memory)

Tags: c#, c++, cmake

I need help from C++ folks.

The problem:

1. I used CMake to compile the 'LLaMA.cpp' (LLaMA language model inference on CPU) project at 'https://github.com/ggerganov/llama.cpp'. It is a port of Facebook's LLaMA model in C/C++.
2. I then reference this in the C# LLaMA.NET project which is a .NET wrapper for LLaMA.cpp.

The problem is that when I run the C# LLaMA.NET TEST project, I get this error:

*

> "System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write
> protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is
> corrupt.'"
> *

This occurs at line 26 of LLaMARunner.cs which is the first reference to llama.dll, specifically the llama_tokenize method, below is that line:

```
var inputTokenLength = LLaMANativeMethods.llama_tokenize(_model.ctx.Value, prompt, inputEmbeds, inputEmbeds.Length, true);
```

And this is the reference to the LLaMANativeMethods.cs file and invocation of the DLL.

```
[DllImport("llama", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int llama_tokenize(IntPtr context, string text, [Out] llama_token[] tokens, int n_max_tokens, bool add_bos);
```

Some older posts say that the error could be that the Platform for Build, x86 vs. Any CPU, is not selected properly.

Okay, in the C++ CMakeLists.txt file, is there a way to specify this? Is that the correct solution?

I do apologize, I am not a C++ programmer and have no experience with CMake.

Thank you.

Comment: Definitely check 32 vs 64-bit. If your C# app is Any CPU and you are on a 64-bit OS, you need the library to be 64-bit as well. You can quickly check the DLL with a hex editor. Frhed is a nice free one. After opening look for "PE" around offset 0xf0. It will be followed by two 0x00 bytes. Then the next two bytes are either 0x8664 for 64-bit or 0x014c for 32. The order could be reversed depending on endianness. Another big thing to check is the calling convention. In your C# app you have it as cdecl. If the DLL was build with stdcall they are incompatible. Try switching it in your C# app.

Comment: Also check your parameter data types in C#. If you have any of them wrong it can also cause this issue. You have the source for llama.cpp so add a function with simple parameters to test and ensure you can call it. Perhaps "int test() { return 1; }".